# Equal integrals using Fubini

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I tried to prove that $$\iint_{\Bbb{R^2}} f\left(x^3+x,{\frac{y}{3x^2+1}}\right) \, d(x,y) = \iint_{\Bbb{R^2}} f(x,y) \, d(x,y)$$ for $f$ Lipschitz/integrable function.

I know it can be proven with Fubini's theorem and  $$\int_{\Bbb{R}} \int_{\Bbb{R}} f\left(x^3+x,{\frac{y}{3x^2+1}}\right) \, dx\,dy, \qquad \left[t=x^3+x, dt= 3x^2+1 \vphantom{\frac 1 1} \right]_\text{change-of-variables} $$
but don't sure how to continue from here.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate a functional determinant when doing change of variables in an integral?

Comment: What does "Lipschitz\integrability" mean?

Comment: for either one of them the equation correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the substitution $(x,y) \mapsto \left(t=x^3 + x, u=\frac{y}{3x^2+1}\right)$ we get that the Jacobian of the transformation is given by
$$
J= \begin{pmatrix}
3x^2+1 & 0 \\
-\frac{y(6x+1)}{(3x^2+1)^2} & \frac{1}{3x^2+1}
\end{pmatrix},
$$
whose determinant is just $1$. Then, (using Fubini's theorem at the beginning and at the end) we have
\begin{align}
\iint_{\Bbb{R^2}} f\left(x^3+x,{\frac{y}{3x^2+1}}\right) \, d(x,y) & =  \int_{\Bbb{R}} f\left(x^3+x,{\frac{y}{3x^2+1}}\right) \, dx\,dy = \\
& =\int_{\mathbb R} \int_{\mathbb R} f(t, u) |\det J| \,dt\,du = \\
& = \iint_{\mathbb R^2} f(t, u) \,d(t,u).
\end{align}